# ElasticSearch URI based query with filter

Tags: elasticsearch, search, filter

I was wondering if there is a way to apply filters to a uri search query.

A bit context: In the datastructure of my search data I have a url field and I want to search it for an exact match. So my approach was to query it with `/_search?q=url:/my/url`
The result anyhow gives me back a lot of documents, even some without anything similar in the url field (e.g. `/a/complete/different/url`). So I assume, it doesn't restrict the search on the url field exclusively.

I do know that I can achieve this with a json as searchbody...

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filter": {
         "term": {
            "url": "/my/url"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

...but our current implementation is specified to work with search uri. So before rewriting the whole structure, I wanted to ask if someone has stumbled upon the same hurdle and came up with a solution.